# elliptic regularity on manifolds

Tags: elliptic-pde, dg.differential-geometry

Hello!

I'm reading the book of T. Aubin Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian geometry. In chapter 3 he introduces elliptic operators on manifolds, but then he gives regularity results for elliptic operators on bounded open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How these results extend to the manifold setting? More precisely, let $(M,g)$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth compact Riemannian manifold without boundary, $T$ be a linear elliptic differential operator of order $2m$ with (in local coordinates) smooth coefficients.
Let $f\in L^{p}\left(M\right)$ with $1< p<\infty $ and suppose there exist $u\in L^{q}\left(M\right)$ with $1< q<\infty$ s.t. 
$$\int_{M}u T^{*}\left(v\right)=\int_{M}fv$$
for all $v\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ with $T^{*}$ the adjoint of $T$ w.r.t. the metric $g$. What can be said about $u$? Which kind of estimates does it satisfy? How can i use the theory on bounded open sets of euclidean spaces to get elliptic estimates on $u$?

EDIT: I'd like to prove the following proposition:
Let $\left(M,g\right)$ compact Riemannian manifold without boundary, $T$ a linear elliptic operator of order $2m$ with smooth coefficients. Let $f\in L^{p}\left(M\right)$ with $1< p<\infty $ and suppose there exist $u\in L^{q}\left(M\right)$ with $1< q<\infty$ s.t. 
$$\int_{M}u T^{*}\left(v\right)=\int_{M}fv$$
for all $v\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ with $T^{*}$ the adjoint of $T$ w.r.t. the metric $g$. Then $u\in W^{2m,p}\left(M\right)$ and satisfies the estimate

$$\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(M\right)} \le \left(M,T,g,m,p\right)\left(\left\|f\right\|_{L^{p}\left(M\right)}+ \left\|u\right\|_{L^{p}\left(M\right)} \right)$$

Proof (tentative): I do the convolution  $u_k = J_{\frac{1}{k}} \star u$ with $J_{\epsilon}$ the smoothing kernel. So i have

$$u_k\rightarrow u $$

in $L^{q}$ moreover for every $v\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{M}T\left(u_k\right)v=\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{M}u_k T^{*}\left(v\right)=\int_{M}u T^{*}\left(v\right)=\int_{M}f v $$

so $T\left(u_k\right)$ converges weakly in $L^p\left(M\right)$ to $f$ and because of this

$$\left\|T\left(u_k\right)\right\|_{L^{p}\left(M\right)}\leq C\left(f\right)$$

Now take an open covering $\lbrace B_{r,j}\rbrace_{j\in J}$ with $B_{r,j}$ open sets diffeomorphic to balls of radius $r$ sufficiently small and $\chi_j$ cutoff functions s.t. $\chi_{j}=1$ identically on $B_{2r,j}$ and $\chi_{j}=0$ identically outside $B_{3r,j}$. By Local theory i have that

$$\left\|\chi_j u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\leq C_j\left(\left\|T\left(\chi_j u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}+ \left\|\chi_j u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\right)\leq C_j\left(\left\|T\left(\chi_j u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}+ \left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)}\right)$$

Thanks to Deane i made some steps forward,

$$\left\|\chi_j u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\leq C_j\left(\left\|\chi_j T\left(u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}+ \left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)} + C_j\left(T\right)\left\|\chi_j \right\|_{W^{2m,\infty}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\left\|u_k\right\|_{W^{2m-1,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\right)$$

that becomes

$$\left\|\chi_j u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\leq C_j\left(\left\|T\left(u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)}+ \left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)} + C_j\left(T\right)\left\|\chi_j \right\|_{W^{2m,\infty}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\left\|u_k\right\|_{W^{2m-1,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\right)$$

By Ehrling's lemma (thm $7.30$ of Renardy-Rogers book Introduction to PDEs) i have that $\forall \epsilon_j>0$ exist $c\left(\epsilon_j\right)>0$ s.t.

$$\left\| u_k\right\|_{W^{2m-1,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\leq \epsilon_j\left\|u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}+ c\left(\epsilon_j\right)\left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}$$

that implies

$$\left\|\chi_j u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\leq \tilde{C}_j\left(T,\epsilon_j,\chi_j\right)\left[ \left\|T\left(u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)}+ \left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)} \right] + \epsilon_jC_j\left(T\right)\left\|\chi_j\right\|_{W^{2m,\infty}\left(B_{3r,j}\right)}\left\|u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(M\right)}$$

Choosing $\epsilon_j$ small enough i have at last

$$\left\| u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(M\right)}\leq \tilde{C}\left(T,\epsilon_j,\chi_j\right)\left[ \left\|T\left(u_k\right)\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)}+ \left\|u_k\right\|_{L^p\left(M\right)} \right]$$

Now i suppose $p\geq q$ so

$$\left\| u_k\right\|_{W^{2m,p}\left(M\right)}\leq \tilde{C}\left(T,\epsilon_j,\chi_j\right)\left[ C\left(f\right)+ \left\|u\right\|_{L^q\left(M\right)} \right]$$

and by Sobolev embedding the best i can say is that $u\in W^{2m-1,p}\left(M\right)$ and it satisfies

$$\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2m-1,p}\left(M\right)}\leq C\left( C\left(f\right)+ \left\|u\right\|_{L^{q}\left(M\right)} \right)$$

How can i gain the $W^{2m,p}$ regularity and the estimates? How can i deal with the case $q$ is smaller than $p$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but here's how it works for linear elliptic operators.  The key is usually to to get Sobolev estimates (e.g. Garding's inequality), so one covers $M$ by coordinate neighborhoods, embeds each neighborhood in a torus (where the Sobolev norms are easy to write down), gets uniform estimates on each neighborhood, and patches the estimates together to get global estimates (assuming $M$ is compact).  The patching part - which might really be what you're asking about - uses a partition of unity.

Comment: With these assumptions i start only with a $u$ that has a summability property and satisfies a PDE in weak form. I'd like to use theorem 3.57 of the book of Aubin locally with a partition of unity to get the same global result. I tried the following: i mollify u with smoothing kernels and i obtain a sequence of smooth functions $u_n$ tending to $u$ in $L^{q}$ s.t. $T(u_n)$ tends weakly to $f$ in $L^{p}$. Then i choose a partition of unity $\left\{(U_j,\chi_j)\right\}_{j\in J}$ and i'd like to use theorem 3.57 on $\chi_j u_n$ on each $U_j$ but i can't get the result i want. 

Comment: Your assumptions imply that the function $u$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{2m,p}(M),$ and its $W^{2m,p}$ norm can be bounded in terms of its $L^q$ norm and the $L^p$ norm of $f$ (with a constant that depends on the geometry of $(M,g)$, on its dimension, on $p,q,m$). The proof of these facts is a simple application of the local results, using a partition of unity (as Paul Siegel says), and is something that you should really work out by yourself in detail at least once.

Comment: Perhaps you could post in your question what exactly you've been able to do so far and indicate where your efforts fall shirt if what you expect to be true. 

Comment: I wrote what i've been able to do and what i expect to be true, i'll really appreciate a hint on how to go on with the proof.

Comment: Could you fix the LaTeX for the inequality you want to prove?

Comment: I would skip the convolution. Just prove the estimate you want for $u$ restricted to a co-ordinate chart and then add up the estimates for a finite set of charts that covers the manifold.

Comment: I have problems TeXing that inequality, i don't know why it doesn't compile... I write here (and there) the TeX string without dollars:
\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2m,p}(M)}\leq C(M,T,g,m,p)\left(\left\|f\right\|_{L^{p}(M)}+ \left\|u\right\|_{L^{p}(M)} \right)

Comment: @Deane: thank you for replying, the only elliptic estimates i have for elliptic operators of high order are for the Dirichlet problem with $0$ boundary condition. If i only restrict the $u$ to coordinate charts i don't have $u$ vanishing at the boundary, do i have still elliptic estimates?

Comment: You multiply $u$ restricted to a larger co-ordinate chart by a smooth compactly supported function $\chi$ that is identically 1 on a smaller chart (where all smaller charts cover the manifold) and observe that $\chi u$ itself satisfies an elliptic PDE with Dirichlet boundary conditions on an open domain in $R^n$.

Comment: ok, but in this way i would have the estimates on the bigger charts and i woluld fall in the situation i explained in the last lines of my question. To finish i woluld need "interior regularity results" for elliptic operators of higher order, and i don't know if they are still true or any reference for this.

Comment: If you have an estimate for the Sobolev norm of $u$ on a larger chart, you have the same estimate on the smaller chart (where $\chi$ is identically 1). Adding up the estimates gives you a global estimate for the Sobolev norm of $u$.

Comment: Yes, you can add that estimate over all of the co-ordinate charts and get exactly what you want. The Sobolev norm of $u$ on the manifold is bounded by the sum of the Sobolev norms of $u$ restricted to each smaller co-ordinate chart, which using your estimate, is bounded by the sum of $C$ times the $L^p$ norms of $f$ and $u$ on each larger co-ordinate chart. But the $L^p$ norm of $f$ (or $u$) restricted to a larger co-ordinate chart is bounded by the $L^p$ norms of $f$ (or $u$) on the manifold. So adding them up gives you $N$ (= number of charts) times $C$ times the $L^p$ norms of $f$ and $u$.

Comment: by interior regularity result i mean something like
$$\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2m,p}(\Omega')}\le C \left( \left\|f\right\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)} +\left\|u\right\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}\right)$$
for every open $\Omega'\subset \Omega$

Comment: When you say:"Yes, you can add that estimate" you what do you mean?
You mean that interior regularity results are true for Dirichlet problem with $0$ boundary condition for higher order elliptic operators? If yes can you give me a reference for this?

Comment: What are the results stated by Aubin? Also, you should look at the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger.

Comment: Theorem 1:  Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $T$ linear elliptic operator of order $2m$ with smooth coefficients. 
Suppose $u$ is a distribution solution of the equation $T(u)=f$ and $f\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$ ($f\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $1<p<+\infty$).
Then $u\in C^{k+2m,\alpha}(\Omega)$ ($u\in W^{k+2m,p}(\Omega)$).

and he doesn't give estimates.



Comment: Theorem 2 (Agmon): Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $T$ linear elliptic operator of order $2m$ with smooth coefficients. 
Let $u\in L^{q}(\Omega)$ and $f\in L^{p}(\Omega)$ with $1<p,q<+\infty$.Suppose that for all functions $v\in C^{2m}(\bar{\Omega})\cap W_{0}^{m,p}(\Omega)$
$$\int_{M}u T^{*}(v)=\int_{M}f v$$
then $u\in W^{2m,p}(\Omega)\cap W_{0}^{m,p}(\Omega)$ and
$$\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2m,p}(\Omega)}\leq C \left( \left\|f\right\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)}+ \left\|u\right\|_{L^{p}(\Omega)} \right)$$


Comment: So why doesn't Agmon's theorem work here?

Comment: Agmon's theorem is a theorem for the Dirichlet problem with $0$ boundary conditions. Suppose i cover the manifold with finitely many open sets diffeomorphic to balls $B_{r}(0)$ for r sufficiently small  and consider cutoff functions $\chi$ on B_{3r} st $\chi =1$ identically on $B_{2r}$ and $\chi=0$ identically outside $B_{3r}$. I'd like to apply Agmon theorem to $\chi u$ but i don't know what is the l.h.s  
$$\int_{M}\chi u T^{*}(v)=?$$
this is why i mollified $u$ (to take derivatives). If i use the sequence $u_n$ of the question i can apply agmon theorem and i get the estimate 


Comment: $$\left\|\chi u_n\right\|_{W^{2m,p}(B_{3r})}\leq C \left( \left\|T(\chi u_n)\right\|_{L^{p}(B_{3r})}+ \left\|\chi u_n\right\|_{L^{p}(B_{3r})} \right)$$
Now to conclude i'd like to have an interior regularity result for solutions of Dirichlet problem of type
$$\left\|\chi u_n\right\|_{W^{2m,p}(B_{r})}\leq C \left( \left\|T(\chi u_n)\right\|_{L^{p}(B_{2r})}+ \left\|\chi u_n\right\|_{L^{p}(B_{2r})} \right)$$
and then sum to get the global estimate

Comment: I concede that there is a difficulty here. If I can find the time, I'll try to provide the way to overcome it. A key lemma is the following: Given an open domain $\Omega \subset R^n$, $k \ge 0$, and (small) $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a (large) constant $C_\epsilon > 0$ such that for any multiindex $\alpha$ of order $k$ and two functions $f$ and $g$ on $\Omega$,
$$
\|D^{\alpha}(fg)\|_p \le \epsilon \|g\|_{\infty}\|f\|_{k,p} + C_\epsilon \|g\|_{k,\infty}\|f\|_p
$$
Here, $\|\cdot\|_{k,p}$ is the sum of the $L^p$ norm of all derivatives of order $k$.

Comment: If $C_{\epsilon}$ is independent of $f$, then  this lemma would solve everything. Is there a reference for this lemma? It seems to me quite powerful.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know why formulas appear like that, i tried to compile with TeXnic center and it works...